# shell script to convert degrees to cardinal direction

Tags: shell, compass, degrees, ash

Is there any way to port the following python function to an ash-based shell script?

```
#def degrees_to_cardinal(d):
        #dirs = ["N", "NNE", "NE", "ENE", "E", "ESE", "SE", "SSE",
            #"S", "SSW", "SW", "WSW", "W", "WNW", "NW", "NNW"]
       # ix = int((d + 11.25)/22.5)
        #return dirs[ix % 16]
```

Essentially what I need is to convert a value corresponding to a direction (0-360 degrees) to its corresponding 16-point cardinal direction. degrees -> cardinal direction.

I could use a series of if elif elif... but that seems clumsy and inefficient.

Comment: `ash`, ouch. Can it call `awk`? Your python code looks like it could be implemented using `awk` associative arrays (and a little bit of other stuff). Good luck.

Comment: Why not run it as a Python script?  Or Perl?  Or `awk`?

Comment: @JonathanLeffler : Guessing that the restriction to `ash` implies a minimal sized OS for SBCs, maybe busybox? Good luck to all!

Comment: Looking to run it on and OpenWRT based embedded device (Meteobridge).

Comment: does it have `awk`?

Comment: yes it has awk.

Answer (score 1):

It must be said that bash has no real way of handling floating point numbers.

Of course, to get around this you can just multiply 360 by 5 or 10 and then modify
the rest of the script accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

Here's something that might suit your needs:

```
D=N..NNENE.ENEE..ESESE.SSES..SSWSW.WSWW..WNWNW.NNW
d=$((d*2))
n=${D:$(((d/45)*3)):3}
echo ${n//.*}
```

Where "d" is the degree value

Comment: certainly the coolest solution, but does `ash` shell support `${var:s#:e#}` and `$(( ))` syntaxes? Good luck to all

Answer (score -1):

```
cat degs2dir
#!/bin/ash

awk -v deg="$1" '
  BEGIN {
    dirs[1]="N"  ; dirs[2]="NNE" ; dirs[3]="NE" ; dirs[4]="ENE"
    dirs[5]= "E" ; dirs[6]="ESE" ; dirs[7]="SE" ; dirs[8]="SSE"
    dirs[9]="S"  ; dirs[10]="SSW"; dirs[11]="SW"; dirs[12]="WSW"
    dirs[13]="W" ; dirs[14]="WNW"; dirs[15]="NW"; dirs[16]="NNW"
   }
  END {
     ix = int((deg + 11.25)/22.5)
     print dirs[ix]
}' /dev/null

chmod 755 degs2dir
degs2dir 237

#output
SW
```

IHTH